# Gulp-less not building LESS when included file is changed

Tags: javascript, less, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-less

I am using the following folder structure:

```
css
|_ main.css
|
|_ less
   |_ main.less
   |_ sub.less
   |
   |_ shared
      |_ variables.less
      |_ header.less
      |_ footer.less
```

I am using the following in my ***gulpfile.js***

```
gulp.task('less', function() {
    gulp.src(paths.less + 'main.less', {read: true})
        .pipe(plugins.plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe(plugins.less({
            paths: [paths.less + 'shared', paths.less]
        }))
        .pipe(plugins.plumber.stop())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css));
});

...

gulp.task('less:watch', function(){
    gulp.watch([paths.less + '**/*.less'], ['less']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['less', 'less:watch']);
```

My **main.less** includes @imports for all the other LESS files.

```
@import "sub.less";
@import "./shared/variables.less";
@import "./shared/header.less";
@import "./shared/footer.less";
```

- If a LESS file (other than *main.less*) is updated the file *main.css* does not change.
- If *main.less* is updated (needed after any other LESS file change), *main.css* then updates.

> How can I modify my gulpfile.js to update the "main.css" file
>   regardless of which LESS file is changed?

Thank you.

Comment: This question is more about watching than about gulp-less. Can you include the watch part of your `gulpfile`?

Answer (score 0):

I could not directly reproduce your problem, but I expect it may due to the modified files are read from the file system file cache.

Less uses the [fs.readFile](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) call to read the imported files. By default this call opens the file with the `r` option. The docs do not make clear that the `r` option uses the file system file cache, but docs do tell you that the [`rs` option](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback) bypasses the file system file cache:

> 'rs' - Open file for reading in synchronous mode. Instructs the
>   operating system to bypass the local file system cache.
>
> This is primarily useful for opening files on NFS mounts as it allows
>   you to skip the potentially stale local cache. It has a very real
>   impact on I/O performance so don't use this flag unless you need it.
>
> Note that this doesn't turn fs.open() into a synchronous blocking
>   call. If that's what you want then you should be using fs.openSync()

Possible solution:

Let Less open the files with the `rs` option. Find the `node_modules/gulp-less/node_modules/less/lib/less-node/file-manager.js` file and replace [line 56](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/lib/less-node/file-manager.js#L56) with the following code:

```
fs.readFile(fullFilename, {encoding: 'utf-8', flag: 'rs'}, function(e, data) {
```

Otherwise you could wonder why your modified file are still in the file cache and try to rsync the file cache: https://superuser.com/questions/319286/how-to-totally-clear-the-filesytems-cache-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

There is [gulp-progeny](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-progeny) plugin that targets your workflow.